# Confused by MATLAB's implementation of ridge

Tags: matlab, ridge-regression, sparse

I have two different implementations of `ridge` in MATLAB. One is simply

1. $\mathbf x = (\mathbf{A}'\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{I}\lambda)^{-1}\mathbf{A}'\mathbf b$

   (as seen on [Wikipedia's ridge regression page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ridge_regression)), with $\mathbf{I}$ being the identity matrix of size columns($\mathbf{A}$) $\times$ columns($\mathbf{A}$), and
2. I'm simply calling Matlab's "ridge" with

   ```
   x = ridge(A, b, lambda)
   ```

My problem is that both return different results. (1) returns the results that I want (I know this by comparing results with other people) but why does (2) not return the same results?

My matrix $\mathbf A$ is sparse, it's filled with 1% 1's and 99% 0's. Some columns contain almost no 1's. The biggest difference seems to be that the coefficient for those columns with very few 1's are very close to 0 in (1), but can be quite far from 0 in (2)

Does anyone have any idea why it's different and how I can modify the call in (2) to give the same results as (1)?

Comment: **My guess**: You are calculating (1) on an *uncentered* and *unscaled* matrix, whereas the call to `ridge` (as per the MATLAB documentation) indicates that (as is standard): *[By default, b is computed after centering and scaling the predictors to have mean 0 and standard deviation 1. The model does not include a constant term, and X should not contain a column of 1s.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/ridge.html)*.

Comment: If the centering and scaling is the the reason, can I modify "A" and "b" so that the Matlab call gives the same result as (1)?

Comment: Hi, Susie. Yes you can. First if there is an all-constant (nonzero) column in $\mathbf A$, remove it. Now, simply center and scale $\mathbf A$ yourself before making the call to `ridge`. You shouldn't need to do anything to $\mathbf b$.

Comment: (I have ignored details of sparsity. When centering, the sparsity will be broken. For very big $\mathbf A$ this can introduce problems computationally.)

Answer (score 6):

This is a matlab program to validate what cardinal said, it is actually due to the centering and scaling

```
% Create A(10 by 3 matrix) and b(10 by 1 matrix)
A=rand(10,3);
b=rand(10,1);
lambda=0.01
% centering and scaling A 
s=std(A,0,1);
s=repmat(s,10,1);
A=(A-repmat(mean(A),10,1))./s;

%check the result
X1=inv(A'*A+eye(3)*lambda)*A'*b;
X2=ridge(b,A,lambda,1);
```

x1 then equal x2

Answer (score 0):

You should specialize the scale in ridge as 0, so it looks like x = ridge(A, b, lambda,0). In this case, the first row of x is constant and the rest are the coefficients. In other words, x(2:end,:) should be the same result as you got by using (1). This is clearly stated in the mathlab documentation. Hoping this helps.