# Ridge regression in Matlab produces different results than direct calculation

Tags: matlab, ridge-regression

I am trying to run Ridge regression in Matlab (`ridge`):
$L$ is some matrix, $x$ is some random vector and $y=Lx+\alpha n$ is another vector.
I expect $\mbox{ridge}(y,L,\alpha) $ to return the same result as:

$(LL^T +\alpha^2 I)^{-1}L^T y$,
but the latter is significantly better. I can't understand the problem as I think this is exactly what `ridge()` does. I even tried with $\alpha=1$.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: This question specifically deals with the implementation of ridge regression in Matlab, so it seems to be off-topic here. At StackOverflow, the question will likely be closed, since it does not contain a reproducible example. I suggest you add such an example.

Comment: Okay, I will try to do that but I will keep it here in case some one has encountered it before. Thanks.

Comment: That's one of the reasons I avoid closed-source software. You'll never know *for sure* what the `ridge()` call is doing (unless you work at MathWorks).

Comment: I don't have matlab in front of me, but except for some really basic functions, probably written just as C calls, you can examine code for functions in matlab.  OP might do that- it will probably also list references for where the used formula comes from.  In addition to the matlab community, I frequently had success with just googling my matlab question.  The product is sufficiently used that this can work.  Finally a stupid guess- might it have something to do with putting in/ taking out means of the data ?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23060/confused-by-matlabs-implementation-of-ridge - comments there might contain the answer

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly my problem. Meanwhile, I see that its about the scaling of the $k$ parameter. If I give it much more weight I get more similar results. (The scaling doesn't matter to me because I normalize before comparing anyway).

Comment: Okay, it appears that when I multiply `k` by the number of pixels squared it works. Not sure yet that this is correct but it's getting there.

Comment: @JuhoKokkala, the link you posted doesn't show up in my attempt to flag this question as duplicate. Could you please try it yourself?